# Google Sheets Row number of Filter+Search result

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have created a filter+search formula that returns me data depending on search fields input.
It works fine, however I was wondering if there is a way to get a return of a row number in the original data table which I can see beside search result?

My Filter+Search formula
`=IFERROR((IF(and(isblank(Search!H6);isblank(Search!I6);isblank(Search!J6);isblank(Search!K6);isblank(Search!L6));" ";filter(('Charms Converted DB'!A2:E);SEARCH(Search!H6;'Charms Converted DB'!A2:A);SEARCH(Search!I6;'Charms Converted DB'!C2:C);SEARCH(Search!J6;'Charms Converted DB'!C2:C);SEARCH(Search!K6;'Charms Converted DB'!D2:D);SEARCH(Search!L6;'Charms Converted DB'!E2:E))));"No charms found")`

Data table:
[image: Data table]

Search results
[image: Search results]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

`filter( { row('Charms Converted DB'!A2:E ), 'Charms Converted DB'!A2:E }, search(...) )`

In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators and backslashes `\` as array expression horizontal separators, like this:

`filter( { row('Charms Converted DB'!A2:E ) \ 'Charms Converted DB'!A2:E }; search(...) )`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant. I am not that familiar with { }

I have changed this:
`filter(('Charms Converted DB'!A2:E);` 

to this

`filter({row('Charms Converted DB'!A2:E);'Charms Converted DB'!A2:E};`

And it gives no results at all

Comment: Got it resolved... in my country it turns out I have to use \ instead.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the syntax for international locales.